# and would be a professionally paid engagement

Tags: adjectives, adverbs

Which is correct?

"This would be a professionally paid engagement."

or

"This would be a professional paid engagement."

Maybe "professionally" as paid is a verb and "professionally" is an adverb?

Thanks

Comment: Why did this receive 2 downvotes? I've voted up just to redress the balance - surely a newcomer to the site can be cut a little slack!

Comment: Please bear with newcomers even if it's the harvest season: on hold, duplicate, migrated, closed!! (+1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Paid* is used adjectivally in this case, not as a verb.

The question is, what do you want *professional(ly)* to refer to?

If you mean it is a *professional engagement*, it refers to the noun *engagement*, so you use the adjective. I would use a comma in this case between *professional* and *paid*, by the way. (Good point in the comment, twodave!)

If you mean it is an engagement that is *professionally paid*, it refers to the adjectivally used *paid*, so you use an adverb.

So the choice is entirely yours, depending on your intended meaning.

Comment: And, if it's the former, then you need a comma between *professional* and *paid*.

Comment: @twodave Added that, good point :)